# Why the result of two equivalent TikZ math calculations is different?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am sure that there are many similar posts in TeX.SE but I couldn't find it. I want to know why the result of the following equal expressions is different? (`cos(30)*0.8=sqrt(3)*0.4`)

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}  
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    
    \tdplotsetcoord{a}{0.4*sqrt(3)}{0}{0}
    \draw[-stealth,color=blue] (O) -- (a);
    
    \tdplotsetcoord{b}{0.8*cos(deg(30))}{0}{0}
    \draw[-stealth,color=red, dashed] (O) -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, [pgfmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfmath)  does trigonometric calculations using degrees, so rather than `cos(deg(30))` you should use `cos(30)`. With this correction, your MWE produces:

[image]

For completeness, I have also used `\pgfmathresult` to explicitly show the numerical results of these calculations. Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

cos: \pgfmathparse{0.8*cos(30)} \pgfmathresult,
sqrt: \pgfmathparse{0.4*sqrt(3)} \pgfmathresult

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

    \tdplotsetcoord{a}{0.4*sqrt(3)}{0}{0}
    \draw[-stealth,color=blue] (O) -- (a);

    \tdplotsetcoord{b}{0.8*cos(30)}{0}{0}
    \draw[-stealth,color=red, dashed] (O) -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So if `deg` is redundant why its output is different and affect on the result?

Comment: @C.F.G I didn't say that `deg` was redundant. Rather I said that [pgfmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfmath) works in degrees! If you check the manual, `deg` converts from radians to degrees, so `deg(30)` is not `30` degrees, it is `30` radians which is approximately 233 degrees.

Comment: Sorry @Andrew. I have compiled your answer with extra code `degree \pgfmathparse{deg(30)} \pgfmathresult`. Its result is odd: `1718.87329`

Comment: @C.F.G This is correct, I miscalculated: 30 radians = 30 * 180/\pi = 1718.87 degrees = 278.87 degrees, the final equality being mod 360. I would guess that for efficiency `pgfmath` assumes that it is given "sensible" input and does not return a number in the range [0,360).

Comment: Aha. thanks for your precision.

Comment: @C.F.G My precision being my initial miscalculation:)